Knitting (?) Markov Chain
I am trying to attempt this exercise
Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n \geq 0}$ be an irreducible positive recurrent HMC in $I \subset \mathbb{N}$. Take two sets $A, B \subset I$ and consider the following sequence of random times $T_0=0$ and for $m>0$,
$$\begin{aligned}
& S_m=\min \left\{n>T_{m-1}: X_n \in B\right\} \\
& T_m=\min \left\{n>S_m: X_n \in A\right\}
\end{aligned}$$
Assume that $X_0 \in A$ and define the process $\left(Y_n\right)_{n \geq 0}$ with $Y_{2 n}=X_{T_n}$ and $Y_{2 n+1}=X_{S_{n+1}}, n \geq 0$.
(a) Show that $\left(Y_n\right)_{n \geq 0}$ is a Markov chain but not in general homogeneous in time.
Assuming now that $A \cap B=\emptyset$.
(b) Show that $\left(Y_n\right)_{n \geq 0}$ is a Homogeneous Markov chain and compute its transition matrix.
(c) Write the stationary distribution of $\left(Y_n\right)_{n \geq 0}$ in terms of the one, say $\pi$, of the chain $\left(X_n\right)_{n \geq 0}$. Do the marginal distribution converge to the stationary one?
For (a) I tried to use that $T_m$ and $S_m$ are stopping times to apply the strong Markov property of $X_n$. However, I dont know if it is necessary to create a new stopping time, or we can apply directly. For counter examples I am thinking of some simple chains like with 2 states, but I not sure if it works.
Any help would be appreciated
